# gitignore based on unix file permissions

Tags: git, gitignore

I am working on a C project which generates lots of binaries. I try to keep the source under source control. However, I would like the binaries to be ignored without having to add them to the gitignore file whenever I create a new one. This is a sandbox of sorts and so I create lots of new binaries as I try out new things. I could build all my binaries in a single directory or give them a suffix, but I dislike these reasons. Since GCC automatically sets the executable bit on the binaries it produces, can I use that flag to ignore them?

Comment: Why not just build the executables in `bin/` or similar, then gitignore `bin/*` ?  (Does that not work?)

Comment: Putting everything in bin/ works just fine. I just don't want to for purely irrational reasons and I'm curious about the capabilities of .gitignore, so I was hoping I could kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend against this. What happens if you need to use a script in your build process or at runtime, but it's accidentally gitignored because it has the executable bit? This could especially create confusion if other people contribute to your project without knowing about the gitignore. You're best off manually adding files (or using a bin directory) to solve this problem.

That being said, gitignore does not seem to support mode-based file ignores, but you can automate the process of manually adding files that are executable.

**If your `.gitignore` file can be overwritten:**

Run this to update your ignored files: `find -type f -executable | sed 's#^.##' > .gitignore`

**If your `.gitignore` file should be kept intact:**

1. Setup a new ignore file (your existing `.gitignore` should still work): `git config core.excludesfile .auto_gitignore`
2. Run this to create/update your ignored file list: `find -type f -executable | sed 's#^.##' > .auto_gitignore`
3. Commit your `.auto_gitignore` if you want to share it with others, or add `.auto_gitignore` to `.git/info/exclude` if you don't. Note that if you do share it, your collaborators will also have to do step 1 individually.

**Note:** If you get an error because your version of find doesn't support `-executable`, replace it with `-perm /111`.

Comment: This will erase all other entries from `.gitignore` in its current state. If we Use `>>` instead of the `>` every time will it bloat the size of gitignore. If `.gitignore` is checked in, a better solution might be to redirect to `.git/info/exclude` which will exclude files locally only.

Comment: You're right, but that's only an issue if the existing .gitignore is empty or not created (or you just manually restore the parts of it that were rewritten). Also, if you used `.git/info/exclude`, that file wouldn't be shared with everyone in the repo, and you'd have the same problem of it being rewritten with `>` or appended to with `>>`. I would recommend using `>> .gitignore` instead, and manually removing duplicates from the file before committing it.

Comment: Say I have 20 executables gnerated, then each time I run the command with `>>` for every new entry generated, I will be adding the older 20 entries as well. I don't think this can be resolved manually.

Comment: True, though you could still use `>` if you didn't care about manually adding to `.gitignore`. In fact, you could create a new excludes file just for the purpose of automating this so you don't overwrite your existing `.gitignore`.

Comment: Interesting. How do I create a new excludes file?

Comment: I updated my answer to include instructions for cases where there should be a separate ignore file. Thanks for your input! And to answer your question, you can run `git config core.excludesfile FILE_PATH` to add a second ignore file, but for some reason it seems like you can't create a third one.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can use `find` to find programs with execute permissions:

```
find . -type f -perm +0111 -print
```

Run as needed to create new `.gitignore` entries.  (Note that this is to be used with care; it will find executable shell scripts, which are source files, as well as executable binaries.)