# git - Ignoring file mode in specific paths

Tags: git

I would like to ignore only file mode changes, not the files themselves in git.
I know that its possible to do that **globally** with:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

But is it possible to ignore changes to filemode in **just specific paths** ?

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756445/gitignore-based-on-unix-file-permissions
that seem to answer your question, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @quant its not exactly what im looking for. The question you referred to is about ignoring files based on their permissions,and im looking for a way to ignore changes to permissions, not the files themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, the answer seems to be no.**

Git does allow some custom configuration for paths using [.gitattributes files](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitattributes), but the `core.filemode` option isn't currently supported.